# How to avoid WFS filtering CORS error in XAMPP

Tags: wfs, windows, apache, cors

The XAMPP is serving as webserver and the website is accessible via `http://localhost/Portal/Basic/`. I am using WFS (Web Feature Service) from the external server `https://geoservices.krzn.de/security-proxy/services/wfs_verb_poi`.

All the data points from WFS are visible with a successful **GET request** and **Status code** 200.

[image]

I would like to filter the WFS service only to a particular category using XML-filter. The XML-filter is served/accessed from the localhost `http://localhost/Portal/Basic/Eissport.xml` with a successful **GET request** and **Status code** 200.

[image]

However, the XML-filtering on WFS service results in the CORS error, as the Remote addresses are different for both datasets.

[image]

[image]

How could this issue be solved in Xampp? Please show me the way to correctly filter the WFS service.

Comment: can you not pass the filter as part of the GetFeaure request using the Filter parameter?

Comment: Filter supoosed to be used, as part of the GetFeature request. But currently it is not because the WFS service is hosted on an external server and the xml-filter is hosted on XAMPP. This is conflicting with each other.

Comment: Is there any example to **Redirect** the WFS-service through XAMPP? 
So that XAMPP thinks it is hosted locally and xml filter locally and solving the cross-origin-problem.

Comment: You should though be able to send a filter to an external WFS in the request URL.  Are you saying you tried it but it was rejected?

Comment: If the filter doesn't work, you could try cascading the service through a local WFS server

Comment: @nmtoken  Thanks for your suggestion. An/any example would be helpful for cascading external WFS-service through Xampp?

Comment: try ms4w documentation